# Writing a Python webserver that can only be accessed from a client on the same machine?

Tags: python, localhost, simplehttpserver

Python's SimpleHTTPServer is very useful to run a local webserver.

But is it possible to configure a simple Python server so that only clients on the local machine can access it? (I'm thinking for local admin tools with a browser-based UI etc.)

Comment: You have to customize server. Here is help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287019/stuck-with-python-http-server-with-basic-authentication-using-basehttp

Answer (score 2):

You can open the server socket at the local loopback address 127.0.0.1. Then only clients from the same machine can access the server.

With an example from [the SimpleHTTPServer docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html#module-SimpleHTTPServer)

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT 
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The question [has been answered here as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268835/is-it-possible-to-run-python-simplehttpserver-on-localhost-only)