# Basic authentication with simplehttpserver

Tags: authentication, simplehttpserver

Is it possible to add a basic authentication with simplehttpserver ?

I would like to restrict the access to a website using SimpleHTTPServer

Comment: Does this cover it -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287019/stuck-with-python-http-server-with-basic-authentication-using-basehttp#8153189 ?

Answer (score 20):

I recently wrote [sauth](https://github.com/Granitosaurus/sauth) for this reason. It's just humanized and properly packaged version of https://github.com/tianhuil/SimpleHTTPAuthServer with python3 support.

Try it:

```
~$ pip install sauth
~$ cd some_dir
~/some_dir $ sauth admin 12345 
Serving "/home/user/some_dir" directory on http://0.0.0.0:8333
```